# Selecting and moving a number

Tags: c

I am building a c program to select and move a  number in an array.My aim is to connect 2 pairs of same number in the array. But I am not sure why the selected number can't move. Need help, thanks in advance.

Here's my code :

```
void playgame(char box[ROW][COL])
{
  int x, y, choice2,num,direction=0;
  char input;

  do{

     printf("Please select a number (1-7) : ");
     scanf("%i",&num);

     if(num==0 ||num > 7)
     {

     printf("Invalid!\n");


     }
     else
     {

     printf("\nNumer %i is currently selected!\n", num);

     }
    }while(num==0 ||num > 7);

    printf("\n[1]Move\n[2]Sign out\n");
    printf("\nEnter choice: \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice2);


    switch(choice2)
    {
      case 1: 
                {
                    printf("Press 'e' to go up\n");
                    /*codes for moving the character up.....*/
                }

                {
                    printf("Press 'd' to go right\n");

                }

                {
                    printf("Press 's' to go left\n");

                }

                {
                    printf("Press 'x' to go down\n");

                }

                    fflush(stdin);

                    scanf("%c", &input);
                break;

        case 2: printf("Bye!\n");
    }



  for(x=0; x<9; x++)

  for(y=0; y<9; y++)
  {     
    if(input == 'e')
  if(box[x][y]==num)
  {
   box[--x][y]==num;
   }

 if(input == 'd')
  if(box[x][y]==num)
  {
   box[x][++y]==num;
   }


 if(input == 's')
    if(box[x][y]== num)
    {
        box[x][--y]== num;
    }

if(input == 'x')
  if(box[x][y]==num)
  {
   box[++x][y]==num;
   }
     }


}
```

for example : 
[numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMTS0.jpg)

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by "can't move"? Please provide the exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, you should remove the word "random" from your question, since the user provides the number. And you should provide a complete program ... there's no way from this fragment to tell what `box` contains.

Answer (score 3):

You've confused the "is equal" operator `==` and the "assignment" operator `=`.

All of the lines like `if(box[x][y]== num)` are correct: you're comparing if they're equal.

All of the lines like  `box[++x][y]==num;` need to change to `box[++x][y] = num;` - you want to "assign" num to the `box` entry, not "compare" it.

But you've also got another problem: in all of the lines `box[++x][y] = num;` you do NOT want to use `++x` or `--y` - these actually change `x` and `y`, which I don't think you want. The `for` loops are moving `x` and `y` from `0` to `9` - using `--x` and `++y` changes these `for` loop values.

Instead you want something like `box[x+1][y] = num;` or `box[x][y-1] = num;` which calculate "one more than `x`" and "one less than `y`" and uses the calculated values, rather than changing `x` or `y`.

But if you do that you've got even *more* problems: `y-1` when `y` is already `0` is outside of the box. `x+1` when `x` is already `9` is outside of the box. You need to be *much* more careful with your mathematics.

Comment: I changed it but still can't connect the number.